# ClickOnceProfile.pubxml Include dll WPF-Project

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, clickonce

I'm currently working on a WPF project with net 4.7.2.

I need the SNI.dll for this.

To inject the DLL I use this paragraph:

[image]

**The SNI.dll must be stored within the "x64" folder.**

But when building the application I get the warning:

> Unable to apply publish properties for item SNI.dll

What's wrong with this? I've only read blogs where they remove such DLLs... but I absolutely need them.